# explode not working, showing blank page, and if I switch it round it works partly

Tags: php

Code:

```
<?
$sname  = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$s2 = explode(".", $sname);
if(strstr($s2, "mydomain")) {

        echo '<font size="12"> Text</font>';
} else {

    echo '<font size="12>'.$s2[0] .' text</font><br />';
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with it, at least I can't see anything, it should be displaying  + "Text" if a subdomain has been set, and if not it should just display 'text'

EDIT:
I fixed a typo, now I get the following error:
Warning: strstr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in [snip] on line 4

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well `$s2` IS an array, so um thats the reason

Comment: Are you certain that `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` contains exactly what you think it does?

Comment: p.s using the `font` elment makes the Buddha cry

Comment: Look at the documentation for explode (php.net/explode), what data type does that function return?  Look at the documentation for strstr (php.net/strstr), what data type is the first parameter?  What are you passing to it?

Comment: You might also want to check out the `parse_url` function (http://us1.php.net/parse_url).  Could be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$s2` is an array i think you want to use `in_array()` function, cause `strstr()` is font string only, not array

```
$sname  = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$s2 = explode(".", $sname);

if(in_array("mydomain", $s2)) {
    // if mydomain IS in the array we display this.
    echo '<font size="12"> Text</font>';
} else {
    // if mydomain IS NOT in the array we display this.
    echo '<font size="12">'.$s2[0] .' text</font><br />';
}
```

Comment: This does fix the error, however it doesn't echo $s2[0] to the page for some reason

Comment: @JamesMayes With this code you dispay $s2 only if mydomain IS NOT in the array, do you want the oppisite? if then add `!` in front of `in_array(...)`

Comment: That's what I want, and it's still not working. It may be cache, give me a moment to check. [Edit: No, it's not cache]

Comment: @JamesMayes sorry i don't get you, when do you want to display `$s2`, when my domain IS or IS NOT in the array? I'll edit my post as soon as i got your answer

Comment: Typo. Change `echo '<font size="12>'. $s2[0] .' text</font><br />';` to `echo '<font size="12">'. $s2[0] .' text</font><br />';` that's why the `else` is not echoing. You forgot a `"` in `<font size="12>`

Comment: @JamesMayes got to go sleep, have test tomorow, it's kinda late in my country. take a look at the comments i added.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is what I get for not sleeping for 3 days. It still says Text [note capital T] when a subdomain is specified on the server, instead of <subdomain> text.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond, when it's not there

Comment: @JamesMayes Sleep is *oh* so precious. I think it's now a "commodity".